# "unpack failed: error Missing commit" but commit exists

Tags: git, version-control, merge, git-merge, git-push

After long hours of searching for this specific problem, i didn't find another solution but post a question here:

**Scenario:**

1. Two remote servers: **git.address-a.com** and **git.address-b.com**
2. One local repository with two remotes: **origin** to **git.address-a.com** and **remote-b** to **git.address-b.com**
3. Every day, i check if something was pushed to **remote-b**.
4. If anything was pushed, i create a new local branch based on the master (tracking **origin/master**), fetch the changes from **remote-b** and merge it in my new branch (**branch-b** for instance).
5. If everything is ok and there is no conflict (i fix them manualy if existe some), i just checkout back to the **master** and merge with **branch-b**, so i push **master** to **origin/master**.

**Description of the problem:**

This workflow had worked very well, but for some reason, in the last week at the daily integration, git is returning me a message just in the push:

```
error: unpack failed: error Missing commit 041460e3edf2f00f75022ce864535ffa2331f1c3
To https://myuser@git.address-a.com/git/r/project.git
! [remote rejected] master -> master (n/a (unpacker error))
```

This commit (shorted: 041460) is from two weeks ago and **exists in both remotes**. But, now, when i fetch and merge the changes from **remote-b** to **branch-b**, merge it to **master** and try to push to **origin** this error is being shown.

**Commands executed:**

```
#git checkout -b branch-b
#git fetch remote-b
#git merge remote-b/master
#git checkout master
#git merge branch-b
#git push origin master
```

**Enviroment:**

Git in remotes: 1.7.1
Git in my machine: 1.9.1
Gitblit 1.6.2 in both remotes

**Tried:**

- Rebase
- Branch in the parent of the commit informed by git and rebase after that.
- Delete local project, redo all the integration steps again.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
git push --no-thin origin master
```

as well?

Comment: sadly, our devops environment had change the requirements now and this scenario had changed. Now it's impossible to make the test again with the same conditions with the same servers.

Answer (score 0):

It may be some error on your local repository. Try this git command to Cleanup unnecessary files and optimize the local repository
:

```
git gc
```